# System Settings won't open – Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'switchboard' received an X Window System error

Tags: window-manager, switchboard

I'm having trouble opening System Settings. I get this error code when I try and run `switchboard` in the terminal (as it won't open by clicking):

> ```
> (switchboard:16560): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'switchboard' received an X Window System error.
> This probably reflects a bug in the program.
> The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
>   (Details: serial 159 error_code 2 request_code 154 (GLX) minor_code 24)
>   (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
>    that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
>    To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
>    variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
>    backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
> /usr/bin/gnome-control-center: line 20: 16560 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) switchboard $switchboard_options $requested_plug
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[A previous report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard/+bug/1033270) linked this error to a video card drivers issue. It would be helpful to add more details about your drivers to the original post. Next, I would try **uninstalling and reinstalling your video card drivers**. If you can, avoid AMD's proprietary drivers.